# Почему foreach по-разному рабоатет с массивом, списком и dictionary?

Tags: c#

Я изучаю C# и Unity.
**Вопрос 1:** Почему для использования foreach с массивом или списком достаточно указать тип и имя переменной, а с dictionary - нужно объявлять ее исвользуя var (и подвопрос: я недавно изучаю C#, насколько я видел, переменные обычно объявляются без var)?
**Вопрос2:** Почему работая с dictionary, переменной цикла foreach можно не задавать тип - он определится сам, а в случае с массивом и списком - необходимо?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour {

    //Array
    string[] names = new string[]{"Name", "Surname"};

    //List
    List<string> animals = new List<string>(){"dog", "cat", "cow"};

    //Dictionary
    Dictionary<string,string> clothes = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    void Start () {
        clothes.Add("slot1", "hat");
        clothes.Add("slot2", "t-shirt");

        LoopTest();
    }

    void LoopTest(){

            //foreach loop goes through names array

            foreach (string name in names) {
                print (name);
            }

            //foreach loop goes through animals list

            foreach (string name in animals) {
                print (name);
            }


            //foreach loop goes through clothes dictionary

            foreach (var item in clothes) {
                print (item.Key + " " + item.Value);
            }

        }
}
```

Это просто особенность синтаксиса, или здесь есть какая-то логика?
Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Уже был такой вопрос. Сейчас поищу

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо большое! Я не видел.

Comment: Он немного отличается от твоего, добавлением dynamic, Но суть та же.

Comment: @Grundy Я еще не знаю что такое dynamic ) но попробую разобраться, спасибо.

Comment: Сейчас тебе это не особо надо. Важно просто понять, что при использовании var - тип переменной будет тот же, что вернет итератор по коллекции, обычно совпадает с типом элементов. Если его не использовать, то будет попытка привести полученный элемент к указанному типу. В случае с Dictionary, типа item - `KeyValuePair<string,string>`, если ты указывал что-то другое, то скорее всего получал ошибку.

Comment: И опять очердной вопрос не связан с Юнити, что еще раз наводит на мысль порекомендовать вам изучить для начала основы C#  =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разницы на самом деле нет. Вопрос в том, *какой* тип у этой самой переменной.

Как вы установили, что для `List<string>` тип переменной — `string`? А очень просто: вы увидели, что `List<string>` имплементирует интерфейс `IEnumerable<string>`, а значит, тип переменной — `string`.

Точно так же `Dictionary<string, string>` имплементирует интерфейс `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`. А значит, всё должно скомпилироваться с типом переменной `KeyValuePair<string, string>`.

В обоих случаях можно задавать тип явно, а можно и не задавать.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "ляля", "фафа" };
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
   { "ляля", "ого" },
   { "фафа", "фии" }
};

foreach (string s in list) // можно задавать тип явно
    Console.WriteLine(s);

foreach (var s in list)   // можно не задавать тип явно, переменная s
    Console.WriteLine(s); // получит всё равно тип string

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dict) // можно задавать тип явно
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " + kvp.Value);

foreach (var kvp in dict)         // можно не задавать тип явно, переменная kvp получит всё
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " + kvp.Value); // равно тип KeyValuePair<string, string>
```

Comment: не думаешь, что дубликат?

Comment: @Grundy: Вроде нет же?

Comment: А мне показалось, суть одна и та же. Может стоить тогда добавить в ответ пример во что разворачивается foreach? Я кстати уверен, что такое точно было

Comment: @Grundy: Мне кажется, тут больше вопрос в том, что есть неявная типизация. Безотносительно к `foreach`.

Comment: Большое спасибо всем за помощь! Я пока изучаю самые основы C# и возникает много вопросов :)

Comment: @Rumata: Пожалуйста! Спрашивайте ещё!